# Why do Major Barbara and Undershaft shake hands?

Tags: george-bernard-shaw, major-barbara

In George Bernard Shaw's **Major Barbara**, I came across the following conversation which culminates with Barbara and her father Colonel Undershaft shaking hands:

> BARBARA. No. Will you let me try?
>
> UNDERSHAFT. Well, I will make a bargain with you. If I go to see you
>   to-morrow in your Salvation Shelter, will you come the day after to
>   see me in my cannon works?
>
> BARBARA. Take care. It may end in your giving up the cannons for the
>   sake of the Salvation Army.
>
> UNDERSHAFT. Are you sure it will not end in your giving up the
>   Salvation Army for the sake of the cannons?
>
> BARBARA. I will take my chance of that.
>
> UNDERSHAFT. And I will take my chance of the other. [They shake hands
>   on it]. Where is your shelter?

Does Barbara make a bet with Undershaft? If yes, does she ultimately win or lose?

Comment: You can shake hands to seal a bargain. It's not just for bets.

Answer (score 1):

They shook hands to [seal the bargain](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shake+hands+on+something) they'd made a few lines earlier, she to visit his cannon works and he to come to her shelter.

> **I will make a bargain with you.** If I go to see you to-morrow in your Salvation Shelter, will you come the day after to see me in my cannon works?

Shaking hands is a semi-formal way of making the compact a little more real. They've both committed their honour to the agreement and although it's not legally binding in any real sense, **it shows the audience that both have made serious plans to follow through with this.** It's not just idle chatter.